# How to use input value as array index

Tags: jquery

I'm actaully out of ideas.
I've been reading around about this problem but I didn't find any answer that suits my need. So here is the scenario

I have some inputs where I get a value by their `id`

```
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="Taco house" />
<input type="hidden" id="pin" value="Mexican" />
```

And I try to use the value as `index` to build an array

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var pin = $('#pin').val();

markersData = {
    pin: [ //here it should put 'Mexican' instead it puts 'pin'
    {
        name: name,
        location_latitude: 43.5391318, 
        location_longitude: 10.3020171,
        //other nodes here
    }
    ]
};
```

If I print `pin` variable before passing to the array it prints its actual value, but once I pass to the array the value is lost and the index became pin.

For sure this is an obvious question but since I'm not that good in jquery I need some help.

Comment: Can you post your full code ?

Comment: Your problem is not at all clear, but have you tried `var foo = markersData.pin[parseInt(pin, 10)]`

Comment: Could you post some more info? hard to understand the problem from your description

Comment: You do not have a pin with attribute pin. You have a named pin. So what is `name:name` looking like? `name:"Taco house"` ?

Comment: @mplungjan yes actually name look like `name:"Taco house"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var pin = $('#pin').val();
markersData = {};
markersData[pin] = [{
    name: name,
    location_latitude: 43.5391318,
    location_longitude: 10.3020171,
    //other nodes here
}];
```

Your way won't work, because the parser consider pin as a string, not as the content of your "pin" variable. Neither can you do markersData.pin for the same reason.

As far as I know (I might be wrong), the only way to do this is to use square brackets, which might be a bit confusing since it looks like adding an index to an array.
Hope this helps

Comment: Is `markersData[pin]` the same as `markersData.pin`? Please explain what you are actually doing here to help the asker understand why this should "do the trick".

Comment: @Zack, I was actually updating my answer to add some clarification. It should also answer your question.

Comment: This is actually working but I don't understand why I cannot use variable to build an array index in my previous way though

Comment: @Fabio Someone can provide you with a better explanation, sinceI am not versed in javascript inner working, but from what I understand, the parser does not see pin as a variable when you use it as an object keys. I think it is intended to prevent confusion, JS can't know if you want to use a string or a variable you declared.

Comment: I see, i'm not expert too, i know it should work properly in php

Comment: @Fabio That's why I said it was a bit confusing :). But PHP's variables starts with a $ sign, so PHP's parser knows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but you can all add $ symbol in js or jquery variables, so i tried but with same result

Comment: @Fabio In your question, you have an *object* `markersData`, which you are setting the *property* `pin` to be an array. In vhoen's answer, he is setting the `markersData` array element at location `pin` to be an array, with a single object. That's how I understand it anyway.

Comment: @Fabio, as I said, I don't think JS is ever looking for anything else than a string for an object's key, even prefixed by a dollar sign.

Comment: @Zack so actually the only way to assign an object index a string (in my question way) is to place a string surrounded by quotes and not in any dynamic way. Is that correct?

Comment: @Zack in my case markersData is still an array despite the syntax. Have a look at this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Reading through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors makes me think this answer doesn't actually do what we think. It is just setting a property on the markersData object, and the property's name is the value of the name variable, and it's value is the array with a single object with name, location_latitude, and location_longitude properties.

Comment: @Zack, seems found the link seconds before I posted it. You got it right.

Comment: @Zack I see, so what would be the correct way to build the object for my pourpose to your opinion?

Comment: @Fabio vhoen's answer will work if you want to use `markersData["Mexican"][0].name` to get the value "Taco house", as your question makes it sound like you do. You could add more elements to the `markersData["Mexican"]` array by using `.push` as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: @Zack alright, thanks for your support, really apreciate

Comment: @Zack, you can also use markersData.Mexican[0].name, no need to use square brackets to retrieve data.